# i can filter my form in sql

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 PHP page and a want to filter my form with data from the user.
my database name : resturant , and my table name: resturant 
please help me
I use php my admin.
I am a beginner.

this is my HTML page

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
    </head>
    <BODY>

     <Form method="get" action="showtype.php">
    <center>
     <p><Select Name = "Foodlist">
     <Option value="">All</Option>
     <Option value="dessert">dessert</Option>
      <Option value="traditional">traditional</Option>
     <Option value="fast food">fast food</Option>
     </Select>
     </p>
     <p><input type="submit" value="Show"></p>
     </center>
     </Form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and this is my php page

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <HTML>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">

    </head>
    <BODY> 

    <?php

    $db_host="localhost";
    $db_user="root";
    $db_pass="";
    $db_name="resturant";
    $db_table="resturant";
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT);
    $con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass);
    $selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con);
      $SQL=" Select * From resturant";
      $t= $_GET['Foodlist'];
      if ($t !='')
        {
         $SQL.= " where Food-type2 = $t";

         }
     $dbresult=mysql_query($SQL,$con);

      while($amch=mysql_fetch_assoc($dbresult)) { ?> 
         <div class="content">
         <h3><?php echo $amch['Food-type2'];?></h3>

         </div>   
        <?php } ?>
     </BODY>
     </HTML>
```

what can I do? 
why I cant filter with where??

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep, $t with single quotes.

```
 $SQL.= " where Food-type2 = '$t'";
```

and for debugging the query, echo $SQL before executing it and see how it generated, and if possible try to execute it in mysql console.

Answer (score 0):

as `praveen-myakala` said. you must change `$SQL` to

```
$SQL.= " where Food-type2 = '$t'";
```

or

```
$SQL.= " where `Food-type2` = '$t'";
```

but remember that `mysql_connect` , `mysql_select_db` , `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_assoc` are deprecated And you can use ‍‍`MySQLi extension` or `PDO (PHP Data Objects)` to connect to the database.

Read [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) (english) or [this article](https://beyamooz.com/php/97-database/118-%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B7-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D9%BE%D8%A7%DB%8C%DA%AF%D8%A7%D9%87-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-mysql-%D8%AF%D8%B1-php) (persian)  for more